# Create order form that saves multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a products model and an orders model (probably better called order_item). A user will create an order each week day and be deleted before the start of the next week.
The product has_many orders and an order belongs_to products.

I want to display a form of all the products where a user can input the number of each product they want and each will be saved in the order table with the following fields, :product_id, :amount, :user_id, :date.
With those fields I can find and display each days order for each user which I can do but I'm not sure how to create the form so it saves a new order record for each product in the form

How can I create this?
I've looked at nested forms but it doesn't seem right for this...

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be a good use case for the [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). It behaves in a similar fashion to a many to many association, but it allows you to store additional information about the relationships in its own model. In your case, you'd have the date and the amount on the order model.

You'd set up the models like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :items, through: :orders
end

Class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :users, through: :orders
end

Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :user
end
```